# how do you use pycodestyle in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, pycodestyle

I'm super new to coding. My teacher is requiring using pycodestyle for a project. I looked at the documentation and don't understand how to use it in pycharm. I got as far as importing pycodestyle. what is the syntax or format to use it?